# PHP header function not working

Tags: php, redirect

I used to use this function to redirect from one php page to another:

```
header( 'Location: student.php?cnp='.$_REQUEST['name']) ;
```

In my localhost it does work, but if testing it in internet, it doesn't redirect.
I've also tried to give the full path (like `http://.../student.php?...`) but still it doesn't work. Does anyone know why and what should I do?

Comment: are you receiving any error messages? perhaps _"Cannot modify header information - header already sent by ..."_ ???

Comment: no...it just remains on the same page!

Comment: Is error reporting on? Are you sure that line is executed?

Comment: Check your [error log](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/).

Comment: are you exiting from the script immediately after the header statement?

Comment: @Mark: i did exit immediately using return

Comment: Can you post the headers you receive from the server?

Comment: @Juhana: i am not sure if that line is executed but just the previous line was executed..

Comment: @bouke I guess this is it: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ritz/public_html/studenti/second.php:8) in /home/ritz/public_html/studenti/second.php on line 466 ; line 8 is where i import another file (require '...'). What should i do now?

Comment: @madrugada: read the error message. you cannot do **ANY** output before calling header(), or you'll get the warning and failed headers.

Comment: @MarcB meantime i removed the output and the result is what i wrote before!

Comment: indeed, not having ECHO before a header is very important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/someurl.php', true);
```

Second parameter replaces previous location header (if any).

Also check what HTTP response code you receive (it should be 30X)

If nothing helps you can always redirect by javascript:

```
echo "<script>window.top.location='http://www.example.com/someurl.php'</script>"
```

This is not so professional but works even if headers has already been sent.

Comment: Thank you all, it worked.
It's strange but after looking here[1] i saw there should not be any blank space before 

     <?php 
and after 
       
     ?> 

[1]http://forum.mamboserver.com/showthread.php?t=49427

Comment: I know it's an old question but as I came here I assume others will too. I had the same problem but the provided solutions didn't help. After an hour of searching I've found out that a colleague modified the file with a different editor that changed encoding to 'UTF8 with BOM'. Sending a location header with index.php in this encoding wasn't possible anymore. After converting it back to UTF8 (without BOM) everything works as before. I hope this information helps others saving time.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `session_write_close();` before and `exit()` after:

```
session_write_close();

header( 'Location: student.php?cnp='.$_REQUEST['name']) ;

exit();
```

Just saw the error message in the comments. Add `ob_start();`  to the top of your pages, under the `session_start()` if you have that.

Comment: i dont have any session...shall i still add what you said?

Comment: Yes you should still add it. Put it at the top of your main file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it didnt work

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/someurl.php', true);
```

So I suggest people to go with these two possible below solutions which worked for me.

using `JS`:

```
echo "<script>window.top.location='http://www.example.com/someurl.php'</script>"
```

using `META`:

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=http://www.example.com/someurl.php">';
```

These two both worked for me. But for some reason header thing doesnt work on the net but works locally perfectly fine. I am gonna be using meta solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `header()` is not working because the header was already sent to the browser.
Use `ob_start()` at the beginning of your page (even before the DOCTYPE declaration). And at the end, use `ob_end_flush()`

Answer (score 0):

Try This [www.psychocodes.in](http://www.psychocodes.in/php-header-function-not-working-php-header-not-redirecting.html)

```
<?php
ob_start();

//more code
header("Location:URL");

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem this advice worked for me. Place this function at the top of your code:

```
function move_to(){
header('Location: student.php?cnp='.$_REQUEST['name']);
}
```

and call that function anywhere with:

```
move_to()
```

Btw, I'm not gonna take credit for it. I just found it at: [Header function not working PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600067/header-function-not-working-php)